# filesystem with invalid superblock checksum error on ubuntu 18.04 boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, ext4, fsck

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS with windows 10 and after I boot into Windows, Ubuntu boot failed with `fsck.ext4: Superblock checksum does not match superblock while trying to open /dev/sda8` and it dropped to `initframe` terminal. I tried to repair it with `fsck` , but it doesn't work. However I can boot into Windows again. How to boot into Ubuntu again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue. That problem came from **Ex2fsd** versions below than **v0.68** which installed on Windows. Upgrade the Extfsd and run following command on initframe terminal. `fsck.ext4 -p -b 884736 -B 4096 /dev/sda8` and reboot. That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me and now I could reboot the Ubuntu.